# How to access a file inside another folder

Tags: python, import, parent-child, python-import, parent

So I am trying to access to a file contained inside a folder which himself is inside the parent folder :

```
_PARENT
   - __init__.py
   - Parser
      - __init__.py
      - myPars.py
   - Getter
      - __init__.py
      - getSomething.py
   - Setter
      - __init__.py
      - setSomething.py
```

What I need here is to access to 'myPars' from the 'getSomething'.
I tried this :

```
from ..Parser import myPars
```

But I get :

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: Tried that from where?

Comment: From the getSomething.py file

Comment: What program are you actually running? How do you execute it? Is the ``PARENT`` package installed or on ``PYTHONPATH``?

Comment: My program is just parser that returns some string, and I didn't knew the ```PYTHONPATH``` do I have to insert it once or at each launch ?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time/14132912#14132912

Comment: Thanks I'll check that

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer, all I needed was to add the folder to the path like :

```
pth = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
sys.path.insert(0, pth)
```